# JavaScript - callback() vs callback

Tags: javascript, callback

Mostly working with Java so when I came across this [code](http://callbackhell.com):

```
document.querySelector('form').onsubmit = formSubmit

function formSubmit (submitEvent) {
  var name = document.querySelector('input').value
  request({
    uri: "http://example.com/upload",
    body: name,
    method: "POST"
  }, postResponse)
}

function postResponse (err, response, body) {
  var statusMessage = document.querySelector('.status')
  if (err) return statusMessage.value = err
  statusMessage.value = body
}
```

Question is why are we using **postResponse** in formSubmit  when the function is **postResponse (err, response, body)**. When we are using **postResponse** how does it know which parameters are **err, response and body**?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`postResponse` is a variable. The value of that variable is a function.

Putting `()` after a variable containing a function will *call* that function.

Putting `(something, something)` after a variable containing a function will call the function and pass it some arguments.

This code isn't calling the function. It is passing it as an argument to `request`. Some other code may call it later.

Comment: Thanks. In formSubmit(), postResponse will be executed with which parameters? Where is it getting err, response, body from?

Comment: "In formSubmit(), postResponse will be executed with which parameters?" — It won't. As I said: *It is passing it as an argument to request*

Comment: "Where is it getting err, response, body from?" — Look at the source code to the `request` function to find that out.